# Polars - Replace part of string in column with value of other column

Tags: python, string, replace, python-polars

So I have a Polars dataframe looking as such

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "ItemId": [15148, 15148, 24957],
        "SuffixFactor": [19200, 200, 24],
        "ItemRand": [254, -1, -44],
        "Stat0": ['+5 Defense', '+$i Might', '+9 Vitality'],
        "Amount": ['', '7', '']
    }
)
```

I want to replace $i in the column "Stat0" with Amount whenever Stat0 contains i$

I have tried a couple different things such as:

```
df = df.with_column(
    pl.col('Stat0').str.replace(r'\$i', pl.col('Amount'))
)
```

Expected result

```
result = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "ItemId": [15148, 15148, 24957],
        "SuffixFactor": [19200, 200, 24],
        "ItemRand": [254, -1, -44],
        "Stat0": ['+5 Defense', '+7 Might', '+9 Vitality'],
        "Amount": ['', '7', '']
    }
)
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

I hope someone can help.

Best regards

Comment: can u pls add what is your expected output as `df` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I have made an edit now :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

##### Edit: Polars >= 0.14.4

As of Polars 0.14.4, the `replace` and `replace_all` expressions allow an Expression for the `value` parameter.  Thus, we can solve this more simply as:

```py
df.with_column(
    pl.col('Stat0').str.replace(r'\$i', pl.col('Amount'))
)
```

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬────────┐
│ ItemId ┆ SuffixFactor ┆ ItemRand ┆ Stat0       ┆ Amount │
│ ---    ┆ ---          ┆ ---      ┆ ---         ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ i64          ┆ i64      ┆ str         ┆ str    │
╞════════╪══════════════╪══════════╪═════════════╪════════╡
│ 15148  ┆ 19200        ┆ 254      ┆ +5 Defense  ┆        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15148  ┆ 200          ┆ -1       ┆ +7 Might    ┆ 7      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 24957  ┆ 24           ┆ -44      ┆ +9 Vitality ┆        │
└────────┴──────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴────────┘
```

##### Polars < 0.14.4

The problem is that the `replace` method does not take an Expression, only a constant.  Thus, we cannot use a column as replacement values, only a constant.

We can get around this in two ways.

##### Slow: using `apply`

This method uses python code to perform the replacement.  Since we are executing python bytecode using `apply`, it will be slow.  If your DataFrame is small, then this won't be too painfully slow.

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.struct(['Stat0', 'Amount'])
        .apply(lambda cols: cols['Stat0'].replace('$i', cols['Amount']))
        .alias('Stat0')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬────────┐
│ ItemId ┆ SuffixFactor ┆ ItemRand ┆ Stat0       ┆ Amount │
│ ---    ┆ ---          ┆ ---      ┆ ---         ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ i64          ┆ i64      ┆ str         ┆ str    │
╞════════╪══════════════╪══════════╪═════════════╪════════╡
│ 15148  ┆ 19200        ┆ 254      ┆ +5 Defense  ┆        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15148  ┆ 200          ┆ -1       ┆ +7 Might    ┆ 7      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 24957  ┆ 24           ┆ -44      ┆ +9 Vitality ┆        │
└────────┴──────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴────────┘
```

##### Fast: using `split_exact` and `when/then/otherwise`

This method uses all Polars Expressions.  As such, it will be much faster, especially for large DataFrames.

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col('Stat0').str.split_exact('$i', 1)
    )
    .unnest('Stat0')
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col('field_1').is_null())
        .then(pl.col('field_0'))
        .otherwise(pl.concat_str(['field_0', 'Amount', 'field_1']))
        .alias('Stat0')
    )
    .drop(['field_0', 'field_1'])
)
```

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│ ItemId ┆ SuffixFactor ┆ ItemRand ┆ Amount ┆ Stat0       │
│ ---    ┆ ---          ┆ ---      ┆ ---    ┆ ---         │
│ i64    ┆ i64          ┆ i64      ┆ str    ┆ str         │
╞════════╪══════════════╪══════════╪════════╪═════════════╡
│ 15148  ┆ 19200        ┆ 254      ┆        ┆ +5 Defense  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15148  ┆ 200          ┆ -1       ┆ 7      ┆ +7 Might    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 24957  ┆ 24           ┆ -44      ┆        ┆ +9 Vitality │
└────────┴──────────────┴──────────┴────────┴─────────────┘
```

**How it works**: we first split the `Stat0` column on `$i` using [`split_exact`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.string.ExprStringNameSpace.split_exact.html#polars.internals.expr.string.ExprStringNameSpace.split_exact).  This will produce a struct.

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col('Stat0').str.split_exact('$i', 1)
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 5)
┌────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬──────────────────────┬────────┐
│ ItemId ┆ SuffixFactor ┆ ItemRand ┆ Stat0                ┆ Amount │
│ ---    ┆ ---          ┆ ---      ┆ ---                  ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ i64          ┆ i64      ┆ struct[2]            ┆ str    │
╞════════╪══════════════╪══════════╪══════════════════════╪════════╡
│ 15148  ┆ 19200        ┆ 254      ┆ {"+5 Defense",null}  ┆        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15148  ┆ 200          ┆ -1       ┆ {"+"," Might"}       ┆ 7      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 24957  ┆ 24           ┆ -44      ┆ {"+9 Vitality",null} ┆        │
└────────┴──────────────┴──────────┴──────────────────────┴────────┘
```

Notice that when `Stat0` does not contain `$i`, the second member of the struct is `null`.  We'll use this fact to our advantage.

In the next step, we break the struct into separate columns, using [`unnest`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html?highlight=unnest).

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col('Stat0').str.split_exact('$i', 1)
    )
    .unnest('Stat0')
)
```

```
shape: (3, 6)
┌────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬────────┐
│ ItemId ┆ SuffixFactor ┆ ItemRand ┆ field_0     ┆ field_1 ┆ Amount │
│ ---    ┆ ---          ┆ ---      ┆ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ i64          ┆ i64      ┆ str         ┆ str     ┆ str    │
╞════════╪══════════════╪══════════╪═════════════╪═════════╪════════╡
│ 15148  ┆ 19200        ┆ 254      ┆ +5 Defense  ┆ null    ┆        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15148  ┆ 200          ┆ -1       ┆ +           ┆  Might  ┆ 7      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 24957  ┆ 24           ┆ -44      ┆ +9 Vitality ┆ null    ┆        │
└────────┴──────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

This creates two new columns: `field_0` and `field_1`.

From here, we use [`when/then/otherwise`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.when.html?highlight=when) and [`concat_str`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat_str.html#polars.concat_str) to construct the final result

Basically:

- when `$i` does not appear in the `Stat0` column, then the string is not split, and `field_1` is `null`, so we can use the value in `field_0` as is.
- when `$i` does appear in `Stat0`, then the string is split into two parts: `field_0` and `field_1`.  We simply concatenate the parts back together, putting `Amount` in the middle.

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col('Stat0').str.split_exact('$i', 1)
    )
    .unnest('Stat0')
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.col('field_1').is_null())
        .then(pl.col('field_0'))
        .otherwise(pl.concat_str(['field_0', 'Amount', 'field_1']))
        .alias('Stat0')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 7)
┌────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────────────┐
│ ItemId ┆ SuffixFactor ┆ ItemRand ┆ field_0     ┆ field_1 ┆ Amount ┆ Stat0       │
│ ---    ┆ ---          ┆ ---      ┆ ---         ┆ ---     ┆ ---    ┆ ---         │
│ i64    ┆ i64          ┆ i64      ┆ str         ┆ str     ┆ str    ┆ str         │
╞════════╪══════════════╪══════════╪═════════════╪═════════╪════════╪═════════════╡
│ 15148  ┆ 19200        ┆ 254      ┆ +5 Defense  ┆ null    ┆        ┆ +5 Defense  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 15148  ┆ 200          ┆ -1       ┆ +           ┆  Might  ┆ 7      ┆ +7 Might    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 24957  ┆ 24           ┆ -44      ┆ +9 Vitality ┆ null    ┆        ┆ +9 Vitality │
└────────┴──────────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Damn!!...Lot work!!...You deserve an upvote

Comment: `df.with_columns(...)` apparently.